# Is there a way to group records by fields performing calculations on other fields in a dataflow pipeline for a period?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to create a streaming pipeline with Dataflow that reads messages from a PubSub topic and write grouped results to a BigQuery table. I don't want to use any template. For the moment I just want to create a pipeline in a Python3 script executed from a Google VM Instance to carry out a process of transformation of the data that arrives from Pubsub (the structure of the messages is what the table expects). In this process I want to group by the fields "A" and "B" and calculate the total occurrences, the sum of the field "C" and the average of the field "D".

The messages published in the PubSub topic come as follows:

```
{"A":"Alpha", "B":"V1", "C":3, "D":12}
{"A":"Alpha", "B":"V1", "C":5, "D":14}
{"A":"Alpha", "B":"V1", "C":3, "D":22}
{"A":"Beta", "B":"V1", "C":2, "D":6}
{"A":"Beta", "B":"V1", "C":7, "D":19}
{"A":"Beta", "B":"V2", "C":3, "D":10}
{"A":"Beta", "B":"V2", "C":5, "D":12}
```

The output with this records should be something like this:

```
{"A-B":"AlphaV1", "Occurs":3, "sum_C":11, "avg_D":16}
{"A-B":"BetaV1", "Occurs":2, "sum_C":9, "avg_D":12.5}
{"A-B":"BetaV2", "Occurs":2, "sum_C":8, "avg_D":11}
```

How can I define a function in Apache Beam in order to do that process?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you care to window your inputs somehow? If this is a streaming pipeline, you'll most likely need some windowing..

Comment: First, +1 to Pablo said. We need some sort of windowing. 

Regarding the transformation. Regardless what approach we take, I believe we need to re-generate a key first each piece of data "{}".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do all of this with a simple GroupByKey, and a custom aggregation. There is one big question that you'll need to ponder yourself: How do you want to window your data?

You need to window your data, because the runner needs to figure out when to stop waiting for more data on the same key. Happy to chat more about windowing if you get stuck with that.

Here is how you can perform your aggregation, and we just "assume" the windowing:

```
def compute_keys(elm):
  key = '%s%s' % (elm.get('A'), elm.get('B'))
  return (key, elm)


def perform_aggregations_per_key(key_values):
  key, values = key_values
  values = list(values)  # This will load all values for a single key into memory!
  sum_C = sum(v['C'] for v in values)
  avg_D = sum(v['D'] for v in values) / len(values)
  occurs = len(values)
  return {'A-B': key,
          'Occurs': occurs,
          'sum_C': sum_C,
          'avg_D': avg_D}


my_inputs = (p | ReadFromPubSub(.....))

windowed_inputs = (my_inputs
                   | beam.WindowInto(....))  # You need to window your stream

result = (windowed_inputs
          | beam.Map(compute_keys)
          | beam.GroupByKey()
          | beam.Map(perform_aggregations_per_key))
```